# SQL DataType Float giving/return exponationa value

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Mst_Stock the Columns are Stk_Qty dataType is Float and Stk_ItmNo DataType is Numeric.

When i wrote a below code to Deduct the Qty from Mst_Stock When i pass the Integer value then its ok, but when its decimal value then its goes to exponation.

Please help on this.

Below is the ASP.Net Code

```
   Private Sub Frm_StockUpdate(ByVal LdbM_NewStkQty As Double, ByVal LdbM_ItemNo As Double)

        Dim LdbM_TotalQty As Double

        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * from Mst_Stock Where Stk_ItmNo=" & LdbM_ItemNo & "", con)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read
                If IsDBNull(dr("Stk_Qty")) = False Then
                    LdbM_TotalQty = dr("Stk_Qty")
                    LdbM_TotalQty = LdbM_TotalQty - LdbM_NewStkQty

                Else
                    'LdbM_TotalQty = LdbM_TotalQty + LdbM_NewStkQty
                End If


            End While
        End If
        con.Close()



        Dim LsM_Qryinsert2 As String
        con.Open()
        LsM_Qryinsert2 = "update Mst_Stock set Stk_Qty=@Stk_Qty Where Stk_ItmNo=" & LdbM_ItemNo & ""
        cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(LsM_Qryinsert2, con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Stk_Qty", LdbM_TotalQty)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()

    End Sub
```

What problem if i use float.

Thanks
Basit.

Comment: Well, stop passing the arguments as strings - use a parametrized query and pass the value directly. The immediate problem is quite likely a formatting one (e.g. using `,` instead of `.` - interpreting the decimal point / comma as a thousands separator), but that's already a step away from the basic problem - use the proper data type.

Comment: Dear, Thanks A lot. But i didnt pass any string?

Comment: `Where Stk_ItmNo=" & LdbM_ItemNo & "`. Just don't do it - pass the ID as a parameter. Why are you using `double` as an ID anyway? That's just looking for trouble. Are you converting code from Oracle? And why are you not just updating the `Mst_Stock` directly? This is horribly concurrency-unsafe. What do you mean by "exponation"? When does it happen - during the calculation, or as the value saved to the database?

Comment: Thanks for your info. Im using SQL. When i saved that time this problem happened. But when i used the datatype as decimal(18,3) then its work perfectly but when using type as float then problem comes. exponation means the value saved in database as "4.3251E-8" format. When using datatype as float

Comment: It's always saved like that - that's what floating point numbers are, really. But that doesn't matter - the point is that you're supposed to format the number when you print it out. I don't see why you changed from `decimal` - it's pretty much designed for your exact scenario (and currency, of course).